# Set selected attribute in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have select group and i want to set selected attribute for object with certain id. I'm tried to move this condition in function, but it doesn't help. Even if i simply set `[attr.selected]="true"`
it's also doesn't help.

```
<div *ngIf="_albums && _albums.length > 0" class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control input-lg" id="selectAlbum" [(ngModel)]="_albumId" name="albumId">
        <option *ngFor="let album of _albums" [value]="album.id" [attr.selected]="album.id == 0 ? true : null">
            {{album.title}}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It's weird because even this doesn't work:

```
<option *ngFor="let album of _albums" [value]="album.id" selected>
    {{album.title}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it.

set **`condition`** to **`value`** attribute,

```
 [value]="album.id== 0 ? true : null" [attr.selected]="album.id "
```

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/BZq43O0PZuAsmyTQLzrD?p=preview**

Comment: i can't, cause value used for ngModel

Comment: I'm want default object with id equal to 0.  Value used for other purposes(for selecting).

Comment: Okay what you want is you want selectedId or defaultId to be zero(0) ???

Comment: I want to show object with id equal to zero in `dropdown`, not just emptiness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126989/discussion-between-micronyks-and-robin).

Comment: What's the explanation for this? It seems as if `[value]` and `[attr.selected]` are switched?

Comment: @Jeppe both are html attribute for dropdown. wrapping them inside `[]`, makes angular binding to HTML...

Comment: @micronyks Yes, but why is the selected-condition at `[value]` and `[attr.selected]` has the id?

Answer (score 0):

```
[attr.selected]="album.id == 0 ? selected : ''"
```

Comment: You don't need the `attr` prefix - it won't work. Simply `[selected]="album.id == 0" `