# Angular 5 *ngFor SELECT: how to set an option SELECTED if it's the first?

Tags: angular, select, ngfor, selected

I'm building a simple form looping through a list of questions, and for each question through the list of its answers.
Now, since I'm building a `SELECT` form control, listing the available options through a `*ngFor`, I would like to make the first option the default one, in other words, make it **SELECTED** based on the value of the local variable `first`, but I'm not getting why the following approach is not working.

```
<select [formControlName]="question.id">
            <option *ngFor="let answer of answers; first as isFirst" [value]="answer.name" [selected]="isFirst">
                {{answer.name}}
            </option>
</select>
```

The suggested questions didn't resolve my problem. Tried replacing [selected] with [attr.selected] but didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assign select initial value in angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46782231/assign-select-initial-value-in-angular4)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/40326743/2878777

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<select [formControlName]="question.id">
    <option *ngFor="let answer of answers; let i = index" [value]="answer.name" [selected]="i == 0">
        {{answer.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

## [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4xqgk2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)